# Eclipse 3.7/GWT+GAE wizard, resource already exists?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, resources, exists

A problem occurs for me when I attempt to use the Google Web Application Wizard in the Eclipse IDE (Running on Mac OSX 10.7). If I attempt to generate a project with any given name/package (using the newest GWT and GAE SDK), without generating the sample code, I get an error stating:

Creation of element failed:

Reason:
Resource '/xxx/war/WEB-INF/web.xml' already exists.

Or alternatively

Reason:
Resource '/xxx/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml' already exists.

The create project process does not finish, and when I exit out, there is a folder with whatever 'xxx' happens to be in the workspace I designated. However it only contains a src folder (with no modules or packages) a war folder (with no library, css, or html files), and does not import the .jar files from the SDKs.

If I follow this same process exactly, except allow it to generate sample code, all the files are there. If I follow this process except uncheck use google app engine, all the files are there. However it is this specific procedure that seems to be causing the problem. I would prefer not to have to reinstall Eclipse and all of it's plugins, only to have this happen again, so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me identify the source of the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Create the Application as you describe except uncheck "App Engine".

Then turn on GAE via the project's Properties dialog.

Comment: +1. Thanks, mate. That did the trick. Would be curious to know the original cause and the solution for this though. ;)